# magnific pop up replace default close button

Tags: magnific-popup

I want to replace the default "X" close button with the classic lightbox cross in circle .png image but can't seem to find an example to try. Please assume no knowledge on my part.
I have some existing CSS in place that I have tried for positioning and colour:

```
<style>
.mfp-image-holder .mfp-close, .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-close{
top: -18px !important;
right: -18px !important;
color: white !important;
}
.mfp-image-holder .mfp-close:hover, .mfp-iframe-holder .mfp-close:hover{
top: -18px !important;
right: -18px !important;
color: red !important;
}
</style>
```

This worked well. I should say I'm using this within the WYSIWYG Web Builder 12 software which means I have to over-ride the default CSS generated by the package.

Regards
Roger

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer that works for me.
Added to the document.ready script

```
callOpen: function (scr,data,$this) {
setTimeout(function() {
$('.mfp-close').html('').append('<img class="mfp-closer"
src="magnific/close.png" width="40px" height="40px"/>');
$('.mfp-closer').click(function() {$('.mfp-close').trigger('click')});
$('.mfp-close').on('mouseover', function () {
$(this).find('img').attr('src', 'magnific/closeRed.png');
}).on('mouseout', function () {
$(this).find('img').attr('src', 'magnific/close.png');
});
}, 0);
},
```